# Using AES-256-ctr to encode Id

Tags: javascript, cryptography, aes

I'm using Node's crypto native api to encode an id because it's going to be shown in an URL parameter, the problem is, it encodes in a way it can be guessed and I can't comprehend why, here's my code.

```
const encrypt = (key, value) => {
const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);

const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-ctr', Buffer.from(key), iv);
let encrypted = cipher.update(value);
encrypted = Buffer.concat([encrypted, cipher.final()]);

return `${iv.toString('hex')}-${encrypted.toString('hex')}`;
}
```

what happens is that the AES encoded id outputs in a predictable way, for example, a number 5 outputs the code `160f20bea36be22f90b092f876f1abdd-55` and note that if I change the last two numbers to 56, the output became 6, or to 54, the id's discovered because it outputs 7.

What I want it to do is to give me a secure encoded id.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with predictability of output comes from the fact that you are using `CTR` mode. Let's see how `CTR` mode works:

[image: CTR Mode]

`CTR` is a streaming mode. As you see, `CTR` mode works based on encrypting a counter which starts from `1` and `XOR`ing result with your plain data. Nonce in this picture is `IV`. This mechanism has a drawback as you mentioned. If we assume that `C(i)` is encrypted counter `i`, we have:

```
Cipher(i) = Plain(i) xor C(i)
```

Since `C(i)` does not depend on input, if you change `Plain(i)`, `Cipher(i)` will be changed based on your `Plain(i)` change:

```
Cipher(i) = Plain(i) xor C(i) => C(i) = Cipher(i) xor Plain(i)
then for block i:
Cipher(x) = Plain(x) xor C(i) => Cipher(x) = Plain(x) xor Cipher(i) xor Plain(i)
```

`XOR` is add without carry. That's why you feel that your result is predictable. But this only happens **IF** your `IV` is fixed and as a result, shows importance of `IV` in `CTR` mode.

I should say that your code in general **does not have any main issue** since you use:

```
const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
```

**to generate a new `IV` each time** for encrypting and add that `IV` to your encoded result. Since you change `IV` every time, `C(i)` will be different for each encrypted data and no one can guess the new encrypted data. As an example:

```
input data              encrypted output
---------------------------------------------------
5               160f20bea36be22f90b092f876f1abdd-16
6               160f20bea36be22f90b092f876f1abdd-15  // Feels predictable since IV is similar

6               160f20bea36be22f90b092f876f1abde-ee  // Sample input, but completely deferent 
                                                     // output since I changed 1 bit in IV
```

So in general, your code does not have any major problems cryptography-wise. But since you need to keep `IV` in your result for decryption, your encrypted data result will be large.